# how to customise get_price_html() in woocommerce

Tags: woocommerce

As I am new to Wordpress and I want to customise get_price_html() but I didn't get the clue to customise it,actually I want to edit product price display as given in the format below:

Retail Price : Rs. 11,999
Offer Price: Rs. 8,075

Any direction would be appreciated.

Comment: Please add code of function above

Comment: How is the offer price stored/calculated?

Comment: PS- the price string can be easily filtered via [`woocommerce_get_price_html`](https://github.com/woothemes/woocommerce/blob/f5e9875548a99933be66f07f90ed26ce2c1909f8/includes/abstracts/abstract-wc-product.php#L1023) filter.